# Convert a Curl Response String in JSON Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I am using Curl to get a request from an REST API. Here my Code:

```
    #Curl init
    $ch = curl_init('https://192.168.0.1/api/invoke/LicenseRequest');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                                'Content-Type: application/json',
                                                'Connection: Keep-Alive',
                                                'Accept: application/json'
                                                ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

#Username und PW
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "****:****");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

#Post
    $post = [];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

When I `echo $response` this show up (`gettype` returned string):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache,private,no-store,must-revalidate,max-stale=0,post-check=0,pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Content-Length: 733 Content-Type: application/json Expires: Wed, 23 May 2018 09:53:48 GMT Server: Microsoft-***** Date: Thu, 24 May 2018 09:53:48 GMT ﻿{ "error": null, "token": null, "statusVersion": 2, "statusCode": "succeeded", "percentProgress": null, "statusText": null, "result": { "productKey": "************", "productVersion": "10.2.3.12921", "timestamp": "2018-05-24T09:53:48.2029026Z", "machineName": "******", "configuredInstances": 3, "configuredInstanceHosts": 2, "configuredClientAccessServers": 1, "instanceData": [ { "id": "l_container1", "usedLicenseCount": 912 }, { "id": "l_container2", "usedLicenseCount": 7 }, { "id": "l_container3", "usedLicenseCount": 2 } ] }, "logOutput": null }
```

So far, so good I think. Now I want to parse the "instanceData". I think I have to use the `json_decode($response, true);` to create an array.
So:

```
$result = json_decode($response, true);
echo $result;
```

But when I print that per echo, the field is empty.
I don't get an error, but the site is blank.

Sorry for my english, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set `CURLOPT_HEADER` as well as `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, then the returned response will contain both the headers and the body in a single string.

If you're only interested in the body, remove the line setting the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option, and your response will only contain the JSON. You can then use `json_decode` (as you tried already), and perform whatever processing you need to.

If you *are* interested in the headers as well, you'll need to separate them from the remainder of the response:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

$response = [
  'headers' => substr($response, 0, $info["header_size"]),
  'body' => substr($response, $info["header_size"]),
];
```

Now, `$response['headers']` will contain the headers (as a string), and `$response['body']` will contain the JSON.

Comment: Thank you. I am not interested in the headers. I delete the CURLOPT_HEADER and now the response show up as an array.